# how to write jquery in body when using aspnetmvcturbolinks

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, turbolinks

I use aspnetmvcturbolinks in own project but, the jquery api that written in body is undefined. I move js files to head of layout .

```
$(document).on('keyup', 'input[name=keyword]', function () {
alert(this.attr("name"));
return false;
});
```

in this above code attr api is undefind!! what is solution? 
thanks.

Comment: Where you need to write the script, Is it in Body rendering page or in the Layout page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have to pass `this` to jQuery to use jQuery methods...

```
$(this).attr("name")
```

... else it looks into the object and returns undefined